# An Entity Object Cannot be Referenced by multiple instances

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to insert a room into my database from a textbox input (int), a combobox that shows all the buildings from the database and a combobox that shows all the floors from the database, I am encountering this error:

> "An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker."

and not quite sure how to solve this.

FormAddRoom.cs:

http://pastebin.com/Cst5bBbD

Data Models:

```
public class Building
{
    public int BuildingID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Hotel Hotel { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Floor> Floors { get; set; }
}

public class Floor
{
    public int FloorID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual Building Building { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Room> Rooms { get; set; }
}

    public class RoomType
{
    public int RoomTypeID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Databasehandler methods:

```
    public static List<Building> GetAllBuildingsByHotel(string hotel)
    {
        HotelDbContext context = new HotelDbContext();

        var buildings = context.Buildings.Where(b => b.Hotel.Name == hotel).ToList();

        return buildings;
    }

    public static List<Floor> GetAllFloorsFromBuilding(int buildingid)
    {
        HotelDbContext context = new HotelDbContext();

        var floors = context.Floors.Where(f => f.Building.BuildingID == buildingid).ToList();

        return floors;
    }

    public static int InsertRoom(Room room)
    {
        HotelDbContext context = new HotelDbContext();

        context.Rooms.Add(room);
        context.SaveChanges();

        return room.RoomID;
    }
```

Comment: If your `Room` class has `FloorId` property, try setting it instead of `Floor` property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using tracked entities (the default EF settings), you can't get an object from one instance of a context and put it in another. You need to do all your work against a single context instance.